# Java FX Exception in Application start method cant start program

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I am trying to fetch a column from database and feed it to combobox. Its not working. I saw other answers for similar errors but that doesn't seem to be a case as if i remove poplist method it works fine. Somehow it could not get resultset into lst. My fxml is in right place. This is my code.
Testfx.java

```
package testfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Testfx extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("myfxml.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}`
```

myfxmlController.java

```
package testfx;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Cell;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;

public class myfxmlController implements Initializable {
        public String dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@exa1-scan:1521/....ORG";
    public Connection connection = null;
    public Statement statement = null;
    public PreparedStatement prstatement = null;
    public ResultSet rs = null;
    public String query = null;
    private ArrayList<String> lst = null;
    public String gammat = null;
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox combobox;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    label.setText("Hello World!");
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        try {
            // TODO
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:c:\\Mydb", "root", "asdf");

            if(connection != null)
            {
            System.out.println("Database Connected!");
            System.out.println(connection);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(myfxmlController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        poplist();
        ObservableList lists = FXCollections.observableArrayList(lst);


        combobox.setItems(lists);


} 
public void poplist()
{
    query = "SELECT * FROM LEVERAGE";


        try {
            prstatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            System.out.println("Got prstmt!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(myfxmlController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            rs = prstatement.executeQuery();
            if(rs != null)
            {
            System.out.println("Got Result Set!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No Result Set!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(myfxmlController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            while(rs.next()) {
                String t = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println("" + t);
                lst.add(t);
            }
            System.out.println("Got Result in List!");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(myfxmlController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);


        }


}

}
```

`
This is stack trace

```
 Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/9727497.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3201)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
    at testfx.Testfx.start(Testfx.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/17342247.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/14208992.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/11822785.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/31501478.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/29531133.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application testfx.Testfx
Java Result: 1
```

Project Structure is

```
Source packages
-     testfx(Package)
-         Testfx.java
-         myfxml.fxml
-         myfxmlcontroller.java

libraries
-  derby.jar
-  derbyclient.jar
-  derbyrun.jar
```

Hello Everyone!
Appriciate the help very much. I finally figured it out. It was one line of code creating all this.
The line:

```
private ArrayList<String> lst = null;
```

Should have been:

```
private ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList();
```

constructor was necessary and problem is solved! Thank you for help. :)

Comment: The error means that the `FXMLLoader` can't find your fxml file. The way you have it set up, `myfxml.fxml` should be in the same package as the `Testfx` class (i.e. it should be in `testfx`). Can you update the question with your project structure?

Comment: The project structure looks right. Can you check that the fxml file is being exported to the build directory (i.e. it should be copied to the location where the `.class` files are)?

Comment: Are you sure it's getting as far as loading the fxml? If you put a `System.out.println(...);` in the first line of the controller's `initialize()` method, do you see the output from it? Or, if you comment out the body of `poplist()` and just add a couple of hardcoded strings to the list instead, does it work?

Comment: Yes its getting to initialize method. I am getting all messages upto Got Resultset. Next it should be Got Result in List which is not there. also connection to database is good too. resultset does have the desired value. but somehow it is not add that string to lst. there execution stops with the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a prepareStatement? I'm not really into derby tho, but if I do it for ie in SQLite it looks like this:

```
            try {
            Statement stmt;
            stmt = c.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("your statement");
            stmt.close();
            c.commit();
        }
        catch (SQLException f) {
            System.err.println(f.getClass().getName() + ": " + f.getMessage());
        }
```

You should always close your Statements furthermore I think you have to commit your query via c.commit(). I would have written your methode like this:

```
public void poplist(){
query = "SELECT * FROM LEVERAGE";


    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query); 
        while (rs.next()) {
            String t = rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println("" + t);
            lst.add(t);   
        } 
        statement.close();
        connection.commit();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(myfxmlController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    }
```

}

Hope this helps!

Comment: The error is occurring before the code ever reaches this stage. `PreparedStatement`s are generally preferable, though in this case it doesn't make any immediate difference.

Comment: Ah alright. Yeah the exception shows that the loader can't find the fxml file but why does his code work when he removes the popmethod? Quoting him:(.. as if i remove poplist method it works fine.)
Shouldn't the nullpointerexception pop up while initiliazing in case it can't find the fxml?

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad Thats what i don't understand. This is basically default program when we create project into netbeans. Its probably not fxml issue. Also I tried to give it path but no difference same error. Also no issues with database either fetching correctly.